# Role of で in 勢いがさかんで、かがやかしいようす。

Tags: grammar, na-adjectives

I stumbled on NHK Easy Japanese upon an explanation of 華{はな}やかな ~　splendid, gorgeous, glorious in Japanese, which is:

> 勢{いきお}いがさかん**で**、かがやかしいようす。

Is the で in this case the copula or the particle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This で is part of the te-form of the na-adjective 盛ん(な). 勢い is a noun that means "momentum", "energy", or by extension, "power", "dominance", etc. 勢いが盛んだ is a simple sentence in the form of "[noun] is [na-adjective]".